# How to create a modelsets by BIM 360 API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360, autodesk-data-management

I encountered some problems when I use the POST :containers/:containerId/modelsets API endpoint .
I use the topfolder of the my project as my modelset folder URN:

[image]

[image]

But it still return 400 when I send the request:

[image]

Is it right to use the topfolder as the folder urn ? Or need to create new folder for it by data management api? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2023 Nov 03**

Now we can create model sets (coordination spaces) using Model Coordination API, even if no one is created with Web UI. In additions, the `folderUrn` can be the urn of the `Project Files` folder. But Please ensure your user account is project admin.

============================

According to [the documentation](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/bim360/v1/tutorials/model-coordination/mc-tutorial-model-set/), you must initilize the coordiante space with ACC Web UI.

> There is currently a limitation in the BIM 360 Model Coordination application resulting in the API not being accessible on new BIM 360 projects until the first coordination space has been defined by a project administrator. Essentially, the administrative process of creating the first collaboration space initializes the model set service container. If you are running these samples against a new BIM360 project with no coordination spaces, you first need to manually create a coordination space via the Model Coordination Project Admin web UI.

And please use subfolders under the `Project Files` to create the model set (i.e. coorindate space). If you still want to use `Project Files` as `coorindate space`, you must use Project Admin web UI to do so instead.